# php, ajax authentication on external domain

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xss

Suppose I have domain-a.com (A) and domain-b.com (B)

I'd like to be able to share php sessions between the two domains unifying logins in a way that once the user is logged to A is automatically logged into B and vice versa.

Now, the problem I'm facing is that even if I managed to have the browser talk via ajax to an external domain via the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header it won't set cookies (please don't tell me "you can't set/get cookies for another domain, this is not the problem")

here's the flow:

A sends credentials to B

if credentials are OK

-B answers with *the* SESSID made in order to be consistent with the user credentials (so that it can be generated both ways ie: login from A or login from B), this will be used later to share the session created on B

-At the same time I'd like that B could write cookies for its domain, but so far I wasn't able.

What I need here is very simple, once that the credentials from A are correct i'd like that server B could write his cookie for his domain (B), I can see from the headers that technically it's setting cookies, but the browser isn't really listening. any idea? am I playing in a dangerous zone of incompatibilities between browsers? technically all of this should be pretty vanilla for the recent browsers.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If domain-a.com and domain-b.com are on the same server, you can implement your own sessions or try to use [`session_id`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) to set session ID. If they are on different servers, you`ll need to use some sort of replication or create an API to authorize users on third-party domains.

Comment: yes, I'm already using session_id, I just want to understand why B is not setting his cookie (B is called from A and needs to set cookie for domain B)

Comment: It does not set session cookie at all or cookie with session id you need?

Comment: Origin is A and I want B to set cookie for B, it won't set cookie at all

Comment: Did you checked if there is some output before you calling `session_start()`? Try setting `ini_set('display_errors',1)` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. If no errors appear, than I`ll need some code to see where could be the problem...